# I want to export the data saved in text views to the external storage of mobile and then can access the saved file from file manager

Tags: android, android-studio, file, android-layout

the code I used to show data in the text view from the database is
here
I tried Shared prefrences too but the app crashes when I execute it.
I want to export the data in txt file in the external storage.
Which method do I have to use to complete this action.

```
public class Export2 extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView back;
Button button;
TextView tv,tv2,tv3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_export2);
    initview();
    initListener();

}
```

Defining the objects

```
public void initview(){
    tv = findViewById(R.id.details2);
    tv2 = findViewById(R.id.babydetails2);
    tv3 = findViewById(R.id.vac_result2);
    back = findViewById(R.id.back);
    button = findViewById(R.id.exportbtn);
}

public void initListener(){

    back.setOnClickListener(v -> Export2.super.onBackPressed());
}
```

details I added to the textview through String Builder.

```
public void details(){

    DBase dBase = new DBase(this);
    DbaseBaby dbaseBaby = new DbaseBaby(this);
    VaccineDB2 vaccineDB2 = new VaccineDB2(this);


    Cursor cursor = dBase.getData();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        sb.append("\nMobile Number :" +cursor.getString(1) + "\nEmail : " +cursor.getString(2)
                + "\nMother's name : " +cursor.getString(3) + "\nFather's name : " +cursor.getString(4));
    }
    tv.setText(sb);

    Cursor c = dbaseBaby.getData();

    StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();

    while(c.moveToNext()){
        sb2.append(" \nBaby name : " + c.getString(1) + " \nBirthdate : "+ c.getString(2)
                + " \nGender : " + c.getString(3) + " \nAge group : " + c.getString(4));
    }
    tv2.setText(sb2);


    Cursor cu = vaccineDB2.getData();

    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    while (cu.moveToNext()){
        sBuilder.append("\nVaccine : "+cu.getString(1) + "\nVaccine : "+cu.getString(2)
                + "\nVaccine : "+cu.getString(3)  + "\nVaccine : "+cu.getString(4)  + "\nVaccine : "+cu.getString(5)
                + "\nVaccine : "+cu.getString(6)  + "\nVaccine : "+cu.getString(7)  + "\nVaccine : "+cu.getString(8)
                + "\nVaccine : "+cu.getString(9)  + "\nVaccine : "+cu.getString(10));
    }
    tv3.setText(sBuilder);
}
```

}

Comment: The app crashed? Paste the detail of the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
public void saveInTxt() throws IOException {
    String txt1 = tv.getText().toString();
    String txt2 = tv2.getText().toString();
    String txt3 = tv3.getText().toString();
    File f = new File("YOUR PATH");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);

    fw.write(txt1);
    fw.write("\n");
    fw.write(txt2);
    fw.write("\n");
    fw.write(txt3);
    fw.write("\n");
    fw.flush();
    fw.close();
}
```

Note: You will need to ask for write permission.

Comment: I used your code and in place of "YOUR PATH" I wrote "/storage/emulated/0/"   everything is working fine and the app is not crashing but still the file is not creating. Any idea where I am doing wrong.

Comment: you need to add a file path not a directory path it would be like "/storage/emulated/0/file.txt"

Comment: I have tried that too. But I was unable to get the text file. So I used Intent with ACTION_SEND to get the answer. thank you for your answer though